# Squashed image in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, image

I want to display an image and text in a recyclerview, but the height of the image get alot smaller when the app is running. It's set to 80x80 dp but seems to be 80x~20 dp when actually displayed. If anyone have any idea on what might be wrong i'd really appreciate som help :)

Main.XML

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

recyclerview.XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:maxWidth="80dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="8dp"
        tools:text="First filter" />
</LinearLayout>
```